# How to change values of a node in xml file?

Tags: c#, xml

I need help. I do not how to change value of the node  with script. 
I am new in unity but I must finish my project.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<bookstore xmlns="urn:newbooks-schema">
  <book genre="novel" style="hardcover">
    <title>The Handmaid's Tale</title>
    <author>
      <first-name>Margaret</first-name>
      <last-name>Atwood</last-name>
    </author>
    <price>19.95</price>
  </book>
 </bookstore>
```

this is what I tried

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using UnityEngine;

public class Sample : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public void Main()
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(@"W:\qz\serialization\Assets\models\newbooks.xml");
        doc.SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText = "hi";
        doc.Save(@"W:\qz\serialization\Assets\models\newbooks.xml");
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your path for `doc.SelectSingleNode()`.  I think you should have something like `doc.SelectSingleNode("bookstore/book/title")`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the full path to the title element:

```
    doc.SelectSingleNode("bookstore/book/title").InnerText = "hi";
```